# Can acetone be used on electronics?

Tags: cleaning

So my local dollar store doesn't sell rubbing alcohol, but does sell acetone.

Can I use acetone instead of rubbing alcohol on electronics?

I know acetone does attack some plastics but rubbing alcohol doesn't.

Comment: Check a pharmacy for rubbing alcohol, I would not use acetone.

Comment: Acetone is a great way to remove all of the coatings from your PCBs...And get some skin injures too if no precautions are taken.

Comment: use isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: Be careful using consumer chemicals. Their purity is poor and often have added chemicals to make them an attractive color or smell that leaves a residue.

Comment: it's good for cleaning edge connectors and removing yellow on _some_ plastics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you never use acetone on a pc board unless you are stripping the top coatings off (copper lacquer (usually green) and component screen print). You can always use a pencil erasure on touchups. If you don't have any no wash items installed (pc mount speakers, non hermetically sealed contact relays, etc) you could just throw the board in the top rack of a dishwasher to clean it. Back when I worked at SCI we stuffed boards surface mount and wash pin and hole items (connectors) flow solder them, then washed them (on a glorified dishwasher on a conveyor belt)  then stuffed the no wash items in then spot clean with a alcohol pad (maybe, depend on who and what we were building).